# How can I prevent my arborvitae trees from turning brown and dying every time I plant them?

Tags: diagnosis, tree-care, conifers

I have replaced these Arborvitae trees 4 times.
They keep turning brown. I cut out parts of the trees behind them, so they would get more sunlight. I Am watering them. Could it be a fungus?
How can I keep this from happening?

Comment: we need pictures, your location, your soil type and how you planted them

Comment: Ok.  Tomorrow post pix.  It dark out.

Comment: and how much water and how often in the first year after planting have you been doing, specially if you live somewhere hot and dry